# Crostini and the titlebar in Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-os, crostini

As many of you may already know. The title bar on/off options in Firefox on Crostini don't work, the a big blank title bar is always there, taking up space and generally being tiresome - something to do with how Chrome OS manages windows.
After quite a lot of novice level experimentation and searching I came across this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1670823, specifically this command: 'MOZ_GTK_TITLEBAR_DECORATION=system firefox' which does the job. I've made an alias so I can type ff in a terminal and I get firefox title bar free. So far so good.
Question is: How can I associate the command with the firefox icon created by Chrome OS, I've played around with the firefox.desktop file to no avail. Any ideas?